# How to count spaces and load in sprintf using strlen

Tags: c++

I want to store the address values in each iteration, and print zip at the later point of time. Right now with the code below, I miss the last zeroes. If address values are 5450,3220,3450 in 3 iterations I want to print

```
5450  3220  3450
```

but with code below it prints
`545322345`. How to make it count 0's and spaces.

```
char zip[100];
char addr[100];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {

            SPRINTF(zip+strlen(zip),addr);

        }

#define SPRINTF(string_in, args...)   \
            (void)snprintf(string_in, sizeof(string_in),## args)
```

Comment: Is SPRINTF a typo, or a macro we don't know about?

Comment: Seriously you doing nonsense: Is 5050 a valid number?

Comment: sorry, its macro same as snprintf.

Comment: So where is your code printing?

Comment: What is SPRINTF? what is addr? what is zip? If we are supposed to guess, you will probably not get the answer you expected.

Comment: What is the declaration of addr, and the one for SPRINTF?

Comment: So where is the format??

Comment: I think we've arrived at that time when it's appropriate to suggest that you provide a Short Self-Contained Compilable Code Sample.

Comment: ..and zip.  I looked at this five times, and I'm more confused now than when I started.

Comment: If addr is a char[] and those values are its char values written as a decimal with 0 being a NULL, then it might produce the result. ;-)

Comment: Question...why do you have a macro named `SPRINTF` that's the "same as snprintf" instead of just using snprintf?

Comment: `sizeof(string_in)` will always be 4 (or always 8 on a 64-bit machine), with your usage of `SPRINTF()`.

Comment: Note that the `SPRINTF` macro, as called, becomes `snprintf(zip + strlen(zip), sizeof(zip + strlen(zip)), addr)`. Looks like `sizeof(char *)` is `4` for you, so a maximum of 4 characters (3 from `addr` + the ending `0` byte) are being added each time.

Comment: @PaulRoub you are correct, if its 5400, I only save 540. How to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much more likely to do what you want:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    // ... whatever is setting 'addr' to something new

    strncat(zip, addr, sizeof(zip));
}
```

Now we're using the size of `zip` (100), not the size of a pointer, and the size will still be correct even as there's less 'empty' space left in the buffer.